# How can correlation id from a process manager be passed to an integration event?

Tags: domain-driven-design, saga

I am creating an application using Domain Driven Design and a process manager need has come up in order to coordinate multiple use cases from different bounded contexts. I've seen that in order for the process manager to correlate event response data for specific requests, it uses correlation ids.

So, supposing that the process manager creates this correlation id and also creates a command that triggers a specific use case. Then, it wants to pass this id and/or some other metadata (through the command) to the event that will eventually be produced by the use case.

But, where should this info be passed? Is it the Aggregate that has a domain logic like for example `CreateUser(userProps, metadata)` and then emits `UserCreated(userProps, metadata)` event? It seems ugly and not domain's responsibility to have to add the metadata to every method on the aggregate.

How can these metadata end up in that event in a clean way? This event is eventually an integration event, because the domain event `UserCreated` is wrapped and sent as an integration one with a specific schema that other bounded contexts are aware of it.

Thank you!

Comment: I would use Message Headers to pass the `CorrelationId`, you can access them in your handlers, and they can still be outside your domain.

Comment: Though the domain events are raised inside the entities and aggregates which are part of the domain. If I have understood correctly some specific domain events are marked as integration events. In this case the domain will be polluted.

Comment: You could consider some decorators to wrap you domain event sending / receiveing infrastructure. your domain events will be clean of correlation ID, but actually the top level decorator(s) will send / receive the Integration events instead and will be aware of the Correlation IDs. Just an idea.